# How to access a value stored in a variable that is in a block in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a list that I'm populating using a for loop. I have this code running in inside a method that has this block. I want help on how I can return myReportLocations and its values

```
private fun getReportCoordinates(): ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>{
        var reportLocations : ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> = ArrayList()
        var myReportLocations : ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> = ArrayList()

        Fuel.get("http://kite.pythonanywhere.com/api/v1/progress").header(Headers.COOKIE, cookie).responseJson { request: Request, response: Response, result: Result<FuelJson, FuelError> ->
            //incident_count = (count_occurrences('{', response.body().toString()) - 1).toString()
            for (i in 0..result.get().array().length() -1){
                //myReportLat = result.get().array().getJSONObject(i)["latitude"].toString()
                //myReportLong= result.get().array().getJSONObject(i)["longitude"].toString()
                var reportCoord: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()

                //println("The coordinates are: " + myReportLat+ " : " + myReportLong)
                reportCoord.put("LocationID", i.toString())
                reportCoord.put("Latitude", result.get().array().getJSONObject(i)["latitude"].toString())
                reportCoord.put("Longitude", result.get().array().getJSONObject(i)["longitude"].toString())
                reportCoord.put("LocationName", "Progress Report")
                reportLocations.add(reportCoord)
            }

            /*for (x in 0..reportLocations.size -1){
                println("This is the " + x + "th coordinate " + reportLocations.get(x))
            }*/

            myReportLocations.addAll(reportLocations)//everything is stored here
        }
        myReportLocations//there nothing stored
        return myReportLocations
    }
```

Comment: the reason why you see `myReportLocations` empty is that the piece of code populating it (i.e. the callback) is executed asynchronously, so that `getReportCoordinates` gets completed before the callback is executed. In order to have the correct result you could call a function with the appropriate locations from within the callback, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to your case:

```
private fun getReportCoordinates(result: (list:ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> -> Unit) {
    var reportLocations : ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> = ArrayList()
    var myReportLocations : ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> = ArrayList()

    Fuel.get("http://kite.pythonanywhere.com/api/v1/progress").header(Headers.COOKIE, cookie).responseJson { request: Request, response: Response, result: Result<FuelJson, FuelError> ->
        //incident_count = (count_occurrences('{', response.body().toString()) - 1).toString()
        for (i in 0..result.get().array().length() -1){
            //myReportLat = result.get().array().getJSONObject(i)["latitude"].toString()
            //myReportLong= result.get().array().getJSONObject(i)["longitude"].toString()
            var reportCoord: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()

            //println("The coordinates are: " + myReportLat+ " : " + myReportLong)
            reportCoord.put("LocationID", i.toString())
            reportCoord.put("Latitude", result.get().array().getJSONObject(i)["latitude"].toString())
            reportCoord.put("Longitude", result.get().array().getJSONObject(i)["longitude"].toString())
            reportCoord.put("LocationName", "Progress Report")
            reportLocations.add(reportCoord)
        }

        /*for (x in 0..reportLocations.size -1){
            println("This is the " + x + "th coordinate " + reportLocations.get(x))
        }*/

         result(myReportLocations)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an asynchronous call. So the list will get updated AFTER it has already returned.
What you want to do is convert this to a blocking network call. (Though I'd use another thread otherwise your application will freeze if it does this on the main thread)

Try:

```
private fun getReportCoordinates(): ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> {
var reportLocations: ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> = ArrayList()
var myReportLocations: ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> = ArrayList()

val result = Fuel.get("http://kite.pythonanywhere.com/api/v1/progress").header(Headers.COOKIE, cookie).responseJson()
//incident_count = (count_occurrences('{', response.body().toString()) - 1).toString()
for (i in 0..result.third.get().array().length() - 1) {
    //myReportLat = result.get().array().getJSONObject(i)["latitude"].toString()
    //myReportLong= result.get().array().getJSONObject(i)["longitude"].toString()
    var reportCoord: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()

    //println("The coordinates are: " + myReportLat+ " : " + myReportLong)
    reportCoord.put("LocationID", i.toString())
    reportCoord.put("Latitude", result.get().array().getJSONObject(i)["latitude"].toString())
    reportCoord.put("Longitude", result.get().array().getJSONObject(i)["longitude"].toString())
    reportCoord.put("LocationName", "Progress Report")
    reportLocations.add(reportCoord)
}

myReportLocations.addAll(reportLocations)
return myReportLocations
```

}